How can i connect to Sharepoint online using az cli?
I am trying to connect to Sharepoint using the following:
firstly i install the module:
  Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell

 The i run the following 
 Connect-SPOService -Url "https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com",  but this brings up a window to login. I want to do it all command line , where by the user puts in their username and password. 

How can i do that part ?
Also the problem is that when i use Connect-SPOService -Url "https://yourtenan......
and i select my name it gives an error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
Does that mean i need more rights ?
have tried the portal but cant seem to set rights ?

Please try use this PowerShell:
$username = "admin@contoso.sharepoint.com"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred

Also since you're accessing SharePoint's admin center (https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com), you'll need to log in as a SharePoint administrator.

so i need the admin password ? But what if i want to login under my email and password ?

I don't yet have the reputation to comment on Karley's answer...
But if you want the user to be able to enter their username and password inside of the terminal then you can use the following:
$userName = Read-Host "Please enter your email"
$password = Read-Host "Enter a Password" -AsSecureString
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $password
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred

This will prompt them to enter their email and password - their password will be secure as seen below.
username and password
